# How to make gameobject collider overlay other tiles/object colliders without turning them off?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision, gameobject

Im writing a simple mini golf game in 2D. Right now im simply vertically dropping ball into the hole which has Polygon Collider of 'U' shape and is placed on tilemap that has Tilemap Collider. I want the hole collider to overlay the tilemap collider but not turning them off, because tiles and hole have different size and if im gonna shoot ball from start position and it gonna land on tile that collider is turned off because its touching hole - ball will go thru it into the depths of hell.

I have tried to put both hole_object and tilemap in different layers but it doesnt work. Even if hole is slightly over tilemap ball will stop on the ground (tilemap). Ive seen solutions like turning one collider if the second one notice collision but hole collider is like i said, in 'U' shape so tilemap collider will be always first to notice ball, which means it wont let ball go thru him into the hole.

I expect the ball_object to collide only with objects and tiles that are in the highest layers instead of all of them.

Comment: You should put them on different layers **and set up the collision matrix in physics settings.**

Comment: This does not work either. Tilemap is in Background layer and Hole is in Foreground. When I uncheck Background/Foreground box ball countinues to hit ground tile thats behind hole object.

Comment: The collision happens between the ball and the ground, why do you uncheck Background/Foreground box? Is the ball on the foreground layer and the ground on the background layer?

Comment: And don't just tell us "this doesn't work", if the ball stops by knocking something, you may find out what it is.